# Limit but no completely block users' ability to edit sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a financial model built in an excel spreadsheet that needs to be locked as many users are using it, but given lending decisions are based on the outputs, users ability to change / edit cells should be limited.

There are 12 sheets in the spreadsheet and each sheet has a few macros assigned to buttons. Given the text appearing on the buttons on each sheet are picked up from a designated language tab.

The vba code that locks the sheets from editing is behind each sheet rather than being run from a module covering all sheets. This is because each sheet needs to be unlocked for the buttons to be assigned the names from the language tab.

Most of the cells are locked but there are a limited number of cells that need populating and hence unlocked on each sheet.

I want to allow the users to be able to:

1. Change the width of the cells (but not necessarily the height),
2. Group / ungroup, hide / unhide, copy / paste ONLY values (not formatting or anything else).
3. Users should not be allowed to do anything else and specifically they should NOT be able to delete / rename / create sheets.

I have got the following vba code (with some insignificant changes) behind each sheet but it falls short of the above requirements. How do I modify this vba code to achieve 1), 2) and 3) above?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "Password"
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rounded Rectangle 1")).TextFrame.Characters.Text = Sheet12.Range("$B$142")
ActiveSheet.Protect "Password", DrawingObjects:=True, _
                Contents:=True, _
                Scenarios:=True, _
                AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
                AllowFormattingRows:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please read> [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Ok, amended the question. Thanks.